# TwinCAT 3.0 Automation Interface: get local netId for broadcast search

Tags: c#, interface, automation, twincat

I want to do a Broadcast Search using Twincat 3 Automation Interface, which requires the target netid to be "Local".
I know I can set the target netid with ITcSysManager2::SetTargetNetId, but I don´t know how to find out the netId of my local system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you changed you target NetId before triggering the broadcast search, change it back to your local NetId using the AmsNetId.Local property from the ADS API (using TwinCAT.Ads;)

```
systemManager.SetTargetNetId(AmsNetId.Local.ToString());    
ITcSmTreeItem routeConfiguration = systemManager.LookupTreeItem("TIRR"); // Route Settings

 // The following XML string triggers a Broadcast Search if consumed on TIRR node
string xml = 
    @"<TreeItem>
        <RoutePrj>
            <TargetList>
                <BroadcastSearch>true</BroadcastSearch>
            </TargetList>
        </RoutePrj>
    </TreeItem>";

routeConfiguration.ConsumeXml(xml); // Trigger Broadcast Search
string producedXml = routeConfiguration.ProduceXml(); // Get the result
```

Comment: no that does not work. GetTargetNetId() returns the netId of whatever target was set before, not necessarily the net Id of the local machine

Comment: That only works if the target System is already set to Local. if there was a call to SetTargetNetId with a different Id before I get:
{"ConsumeXml failed. \nBroadcast search only works on local target system. Please change target system to local system!\nError parsing: TreeItem/RoutePrj/TargetList/BroadcastSearch"}

Comment: Ok, now I understand what you did..I updated the answer

Comment: awesome, AmsNetId.Local.ToString() is exactly what I was looking for but failed to find in the API doku. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As I could not find a way to get the local AmsNetId via Automation Interface API calls here is the workaround I came up with:

```
  var key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Beckhoff\TwinCAT\System");
  var localNetId = string.Join(".", (byte[])key.GetValue("AmsNetId"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem (needed to do broadcast search using the automation interface). I don't have access to that code right now but I remember it as I either didn't need the local NetId to do the broadcast search or I used "127.0.0.1.1.1" as NetId.

Comment: I tried 127.0.0.1.1.1" as NetId but still get the exception: ConsumeXml failed. 
Broadcast search only works on local target system. Please change target system to local system!
Error parsing: TreeItem/RoutePrj/TargetList/BroadcastSearch